# How do I use regex to remove non-space whitespace and special characters

Tags: python, regex, nltk

I've got the following working pretty well to remove non-space whitespace characters, so \n, \r apply the most:

```
nowhitespace = re.split(r'[ \t\n\r]+', text)
```

However, I also want to remove punctuation and special characters. Found this online `toker = RegexpTokenizer(r'((?<=[^\w\s])\w(?=[^\w\s])|(\W))+', gaps=True)` for doing so, but I'm not familiar enough with regex to do the job.
Goal is to eventually have all the words in the input string counted, and stored in a dictionary with the counts of the words

Comment: Why not use just `r'\W+'`?

Comment: You can play around with e.g. https://regex101.com to understand what a regex does.

Comment: `re.sub(r'[\t\n\r\p]', '', text)`

Comment: I'm confused; you say your current pattern removes non-space whitespace characters, but that character set *does* contain a space

Comment: I think `r'\W+'` would work. Thanks @CAustin I didn't catch that until just now...

Comment: What is in your input string? If you want to tokenize some natural language text, maybe you should try  [Unitok](http://corpus.tools/wiki/Unitok)